# File is saving to FileSystem.documentDirectory but i can't see the files when i go the files manager, react native expo

Tags: javascript, excel, react-native, expo, filesystems

I am building a function in react native expo that saves a state variable array in react native expo to excel file. I am getting a success message and when i console log the directory i get the files list but when i go the file manager of my phone i can't see the files the directory Documents is empty even though i created the directory in the code. I need your help please.

When i console log the directory name i get this :
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/stopwatch

and the FileSystem.documentDirectory contains these files but i dont see Downloads, Documents, Pictures and all other folders

```
DIR Array [
  ".com.google.firebase.crashlytics.files.v2:host.exp.exponent",
  "generatefid.lock",
  "ExperienceData",
  "UNVERSIONED",
  "profileInstalled",
  "PersistedInstallation.W0RFRkFVTFRd+MTozNjczMTUxNzQ2OTM6YW5kcm9pZDpmOTY4ZWZiYjQxZDFmYTdh.json",
  "profileinstaller_profileWrittenFor_lastUpdateTime.dat",
  ".expo-internal",
  "Stopwatch.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch",
  "stopwatch",
  "BridgeReactNativeDevBundle.js",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_19-51-51.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_19-51-57.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_19-52-57.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_20-09-21.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_20-09-40.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_20-09-59.xlsx",
  "Stopwatch-2024-01-14_20-18-45.xlsx",
  "dev.expo.modules.core.logging.dev.expo.updates",
  "Documents",
]
```

I am testing my app using expo go on my real device

here is my code

```
const writeArrayToExcel = async (dataArray) => {
    const resultsMade = [["lap", "time"]];
    dataArray.map((lapTime, index) => {
        const lapName = `${lapWord} ${index + 1}`;
        const valLap = `${displayTime(lapTime).hours}:${displayTime(lapTime).minutesSeconds}:${displayTime(lapTime).centiseconds}`;
        resultsMade.push([lapName, valLap]);
    })

    let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    let ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(resultsMade);

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    
    const base64 = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'base64' });

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const formattedDate = `${currentDate.getFullYear()}-${(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}_${currentDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${currentDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${currentDate.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;

    const filename = FileSystem.documentDirectory + `stopwatch/Stopwatch-${formattedDate}.xlsx`;

    const metaDataDir = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'stopwatch');
    const isDir = metaDataDir.isDirectory;
    if (!isDir) {
        try {
            await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
                FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'stopwatch',
                { intermediates: true }
            );
            console.log("directory created");
        } catch (e) {
            //console.info("ERROR", e);
            console.log("error: ", e);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("is directory");
    }

    try {
        const isDir = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'stopwatch');
        console.info("DIR", isDir);
    } catch (e) {
        console.info("ERROR", e);
    }

    // FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filename, base64, {
    //     encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64
    // }).then(() => {
    //     //Sharing.shareAsync(filename);
    // });
    FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filename, base64, { encoding: 'base64' }).then(() => {
        //Sharing.shareAsync(filename);
        Alert.alert("File saved successfully");
    }).catch((error) => Alert.alert('Error:', error.message));
};
```